# Why does Quarkus ignore my HttpAuthenticationMechanism but not my ContainerRequestFilter?

Tags: java, security, quarkus, http-authentication

I have a custom security module for Java EE applications. It follows  the JSR-375 specification and it provides its own IdentityStore, as well as a custom HttpAuthenticationMechanism* and a ContainerRequestFilter.

I've been trying to make it work with a Quarkus microservice, yet it completely ignores my HttpAuthenticationMechanism even though it runs ContainerRequestFilter. It seems like quarkus uses its own HttpAuthenticationMechanism* , and it always overrides my own.

I tried using annotations such as @Provider and @PreMatching, as one can do for a [custom ContainerRequestFilter](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-customization#jaxrs-security-context), but the class is still ignored.

Any suggestions?

*Meaning an implementation of *javax.security.enterprise.authentication.mechanism.http*.HttpAuthenticationMechanism, which has nothing to do with the *io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security*.HttpAuthenticationMechanism included in quarkus security.

Comment: `ContainerRequestFilter` comes from JAX-RS, which is supported in Quarkus (via the RESTEasy or RESTEasy Reactive projects). On the other hand, Quarkus does _not_ support Jakarta Security, where `HttpAuthenticationMechanism` comes from.

Comment: Sort of a disappointment, if you ask me... Thank you for the info nevertheless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Ladicek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/742081/ladicek) pointed out, Quarkus does not support Jakarta Security, hence that my HttpAuthenticationMechanism is ignored.